# Adding a Gps Layer to my android application using arcgis runtime sdk in android studio

Tags: android, runtime, arcgis

I am trying to add a GPS layer to my map in my app. 
the problem is that am not getting a good result from the code. Am getting a red highlights on some of the codes.
This is code below.

// create the tiled layer and add to map (could also be an ArcGISLocalTiledLayer)

```
ArcGISTiledLayer tiledLayer = new ArcGISTiledLayer(
        "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");


map.getLayers().add(tiledLayer);

// create a GPS layer and add to map
GPSLayer gpsLayer = new GPSLayer();
map.getLayers().add(gpsLayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LocationDisplay instead of GPSLayer

```
// get the LocationDisplay from MapView
LocationDisplay mLocationDisplay = mMapView.getLocationDisplay();
mLocationDisplay.start();
```

Don't forget to add these lines in your manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />     
</manifest>
```

Look at samples for more details:
https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/java/display-device-location